# Почему таблица не ставится по центру (JSP, CSS)

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Я пишу сайт и нужно чтобы таблица была по центру, а таблица студент там где меню

[image: Она у меня высвечивается где меню хотя я написал код чтобы ровно по центру]

Вот мой код css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica;

}

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0.5% 0px 0.5%; 
    background: transparent;
    float:left;
    position: fixed;
}

header #logo {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

header #logo span {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
}

@media (min-width: 701px){
    #logo {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    #about {
        float: right;
        width: 67%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px){
    #logo {
        margin-top: 15px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.5em;

    }
    #about {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

#about {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#about > a {color: #red}

#about > a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }

 #about > a:not(:last-child){
     margin-right: 7%;
 }

 .fixed {
     z-index: 5000;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
 }

 header.fixed #logo {
     color: #343434;
 }

 .fixed #about a {color: #343434}
 .fixed #about a:hover {color: #7c7c7c}


 #top {
     width: 100%;
     height: 1000px;
     background-image: url(https://edtechswami.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/02ciutatartsiciencies.png);
     background-blend-mode: multiply;

     background-size: cover;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 3em;
}


@media (min-width:1001px){
    #top {
        font-size: 3em;
        color: red;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1000px)and (min-width:651px){
    #top {
        font-size: 3em;

    }
}
@media (max-width:650px){
    #top {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding-top: 50%;
    }
}

#top h1 {
    padding-top: 20%; 
}

#top h3 {
    color: brown;

}

#main {

   float: left;
   background-color: white;
   border-top: 2px solid silver;
   color: black;
   font-size: 1.3em;
}

@media (min-width:1401px){
    #main {
        padding: 100px 20%;
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px){
    #main{
        padding: 100px 10%;
        width: 80%;
    } 
}

@media (max-width:700px){
    #main div{
        width: 98%!important;
        margin-bottom: 20px;


    }

}


#main div{
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float:left;
}
#main h2 {font-size: 3em}
#main span {color: black}


input[type=text] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;

}




.addstudent {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto auto;

}
```

А вот JSP

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 26.02.2019, 17:35:27
    Author     : Adil
--%>

<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 26.02.2019, 15:07:21
    Author     : Adil
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo" onclick="slowScroll('#top')">
                <span>ШКОЛА им. Стива Джобса</span>
            </div>
            <div id="about">
                <a href="#">Образование</a>
                <a href="student.jsp">Ученики</a>
                <a href="#">Медиа</a>
                <a href="#">О нас</a>
            </div>


        </header>

        <div class="addstudent">
         <h1>Student</h1>
            <form action="firstdbserv" method="Post">
            Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>     
            Surname : <input type="text" name="surname"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
         </div>


    <div id="main">


    </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function slowScroll(id){
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top   
            }, 500);
            }

            $(document).on("scroll", function (){
                if($(window).scrollTop()===0)
                    $("header").removeClass("fixed");
                else
                    $("header").attr("class", "fixed");
            });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Кто-то еще делает меню на флоатах?

Comment: а что это не правильно?

Comment: Почитайте про flex

Comment: Попробуй fixed-лойаут.